# Turn a data frame into a ts in R

Tags: r, csv

I want to turn a list data structure into a `double` data structure:

Starting list data from my CSV.

```
> my_data = read.csv("time series test.csv", header = TRUE)
> my_data
        Date    Value
1   1/1/2014 123.0000
2   1/2/2014 128.5693
3   1/3/2014 129.1474
4   1/4/2014 130.1361
5   1/5/2014 137.9758
6   1/6/2014 141.0548
7   1/7/2014 141.3517
8   1/8/2014 142.1449
9   1/9/2014 142.1479
10 1/10/2014 149.8912
```

Example double:

```
> nottem
      Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr  May  Jun  Jul  Aug  Sep  Oct  Nov  Dec
1920 40.6 40.8 44.4 46.7 54.1 58.5 57.7 56.4 54.3 50.5 42.9 39.8
1921 44.2 39.8 45.1 47.0 54.1 58.7 66.3 59.9 57.0 54.2 39.7 42.8
1922 37.5 38.7 39.5 42.1 55.7 57.8 56.8 54.3 54.3 47.1 41.8 41.7
1923 41.8 40.1 42.9 45.8 49.2 52.7 64.2 59.6 54.4 49.2 36.3 37.6
1924 39.3 37.5 38.3 45.5 53.2 57.7 60.8 58.2 56.4 49.8 44.4 43.6
1925 40.0 40.5 40.8 45.1 53.8 59.4 63.5 61.0 53.0 50.0 38.1 36.3
1926 39.2 43.4 43.4 48.9 50.6 56.8 62.5 62.0 57.5 46.7 41.6 39.8
1927 39.4 38.5 45.3 47.1 51.7 55.0 60.4 60.5 54.7 50.3 42.3 35.2
1928 40.8 41.1 42.8 47.3 50.9 56.4 62.2 60.5 55.4 50.2 43.0 37.3
1929 34.8 31.3 41.0 43.9 53.1 56.9 62.5 60.3 59.8 49.2 42.9 41.9
1930 41.6 37.1 41.2 46.9 51.2 60.4 60.1 61.6 57.0 50.9 43.0 38.8
1931 37.1 38.4 38.4 46.5 53.5 58.4 60.6 58.2 53.8 46.6 45.5 40.6
1932 42.4 38.4 40.3 44.6 50.9 57.0 62.1 63.5 56.3 47.3 43.6 41.8
1933 36.2 39.3 44.5 48.7 54.2 60.8 65.5 64.9 60.1 50.2 42.1 35.8
1934 39.4 38.2 40.4 46.9 53.4 59.6 66.5 60.4 59.2 51.2 42.8 45.8
1935 40.0 42.6 43.5 47.1 50.0 60.5 64.6 64.0 56.8 48.6 44.2 36.4
1936 37.3 35.0 44.0 43.9 52.7 58.6 60.0 61.1 58.1 49.6 41.6 41.3
1937 40.8 41.0 38.4 47.4 54.1 58.6 61.4 61.8 56.3 50.9 41.4 37.1
1938 42.1 41.2 47.3 46.6 52.4 59.0 59.6 60.4 57.0 50.7 47.8 39.2
1939 39.4 40.9 42.4 47.8 52.4 58.0 60.7 61.8 58.2 46.7 46.6 37.8
```

So how do I turn my_data into the same structure as nottem, so I can use it with STL()? `plot(stl(nottem, "per"))`

Comment: I tried coercion 

`as.double(dat)
Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'`

Comment: What is `class(nottem)`? It looks like it's a `ts` object. -- Ah, I see it's a build in dataset. and it is a `ts` object. Try using the `ts()` function to convert your data.frame to a time series object.

Comment: Thanks MrFlick, ts() works great :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the ts function. c(2014,1) is January 2014.

```
 myts <- ts(my_data[,2], start = c(2014,1), frequency = 12)
```

Comment: Thanks germcd, do you have a method that does not requiring hardcoding in dates? This should take arbitrary date data.

Comment: Sorry i read the dates as d/m/y. Try to aggregate the data by month

Comment: as.numeric and strftime could be used to get the year and month from the date